# Visual Studio Fortran Stuck at Reassigning values from one variable to another

Tags: variables, fortran, variable-assignment

See attached screenshot.

I ran the code, stopped it at a break point, and F11 the steps until the line ccs2 = ccs2_2.

I checked both of these variables have the same dimensions, same number of elements that actually have value (they are both 6x6x10000 and only the first 6x6x219 elements have values).

I have ran this algorithm before and I have never had this problem. What you see in the screenshot is the visual studio stuck at this point with no error and no notifications for what seems like forever (been at least 10 minutes for each time I tried) when I pressed F11 to try to execute ccs2 = ccs2_2.

I checked I don't have any memory or CPU problems. When I pause the execution from the top, the progress marker goes back to the line and when I checked the variables, I find the first 6x6x219 values now match up, but the program won't advance forward.[image]

Updates: I attempted to limit the range to just the elements that have values such as ccs2(1:6,1:6,1:219) = ccs2_2(1:6,1:6,1:219). It still takes a long time, but for some reason, visual studio reports that it only took 2059 ms, but the actual time was definitely way more than 20 seconds. I changed heap arrays from 0 back to nothing and the new time is supposedly 1978 ms but it definitely took more than 19 seconds.

I tried using an explicit loop to assign only the elements with value and it took less than 1 ms.

Comment: Might still be a stack problem (as far as I know on windows the stack size is still limited by a program :-( ). What happens when you explicitly do the assignment with  by means of a loop?

Comment: @albert I just limited the range of assignment with ccs2(1:6,1:6,1:219) = ccs2_2(1:6,1:6,1:219) and after a long while it did finish. I currently have heap array set to 0, could that have done it? I will check the speed of explicit assignment with a loop

Comment: I don't know what you mean by " I currently have heap array set to 0". The assignment in the loop should not be a problem (provided you use the right order of the indices!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you step over a huge array assignment statement, the debugger, internally, does single step by instruction until the statement number changes. I see your arrays are very large, and the debugger isn't "stuck", it is just taking a long time to step over.

Try as an alternative setting a breakpoint on the next statement and hitting Go.

Comment: You are right. When I just hit go with a stop point, it went as usual. Thanks!